# Segmentation fault in openMP program with SSE instructions with threads > 4

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, openmp, sse

I wrote a simple C++ openMP program that uses SSE instructions, and I am facing a segmentation fault when the number of threads is bigger than 4. I am using g++ on Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <omp.h>

unsigned **a;

void f(int input_index){
    int j;
    __m128i* t = (__m128i*) a[input_index];
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            t[j] = _mm_set1_epi32(input_index* lenS);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i,j,nThreads,tid;
bitD = new unsigned*[4];
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    bitD[i] = new unsigned[16];

omp_set_num_threads(8); 

#pragma omp parallel private(i,nThreads,tid)
{
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    nThreads = omp_get_num_threads();                
    for(i=0; i<(4/nThreads); i++){
            f(i*nThreads+tid);                        
     }              
}


for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    for(j=0; j<16; j++)
        printf("a[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,bitD[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: I recommend including the entire fault message.

Comment: I trimmed the title and problem intro to be more easily readable, and removed a redundant plea for help. I also added a tag to increase visibility. Dan is correct, though; without full error details this question may not be answerable.

Comment: How are you allocating memory for `a` ? My guess is that you're not always getting 16 byte aligned memory.

Comment: I guess `a` should be renamed in `bitD`. But in fact, you never have a problem with the SSE instructions if you use more than 4 threads. In this case the function `f` gets never called, because the loop is never entered. So your problem is not reproducible for me and works without problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I found the problem with my code, for more than 4 threads, the index (i*nThreads+tid) is out of array's boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment above, your problem is not related with the use of SSE instructions (at least not for the code you've posted). The reason is that if you use more than 4 threads, the loop

```
for(i=0; i<(4/nThreads); i++)  /* (4/nThreads) == 0 */
```

is never entered and function `f` gets never called.

The conclusion for this is that the values of `bitD[i][j]` are uninitialized in case of more than 4 threads. But this normally should not lead to a segmentation fault. To be safe, you can initialize the memory in your allocation:

```
bitD[i] = new unsigned[16]();
```

Note the `()` at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I found the problem with my code, for more than 4 threads, the index (i*nThreads+tid) is out of array's boundary.